# Eigenvectors of the composition of multiplication by a scalar and translation

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Today I was thinking that since we know the eigenvectors of the multiplication by a scalar operator ($f(x)=x$) and for translation operator ($f(x)=e^{ax}$, $a\in\mathbb{R}$), their composition will give eigenvectors very easy to find. I tried for example to make some compositions with the solutions that we already knew, but I was unsuccessful to find the answer. Can someone indicate me some ideas to proceed here?

Comment: The context of your question appears unclear to me. What are these operators acting on?

Comment: What are the eigenvectors of $f(x) = e^{ax}$?

Comment: Trying to be clear:

Multiplication by a scalar operator: 

$\hat{\alpha}:\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R})$, 
$\hat{\alpha}f(x)=\alpha f(x), \alpha \in\mathbb{R}$. 

Translation operator: 

$\hat{\tau}:\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow\mathcal{F}(\mathbb{R})$, $\hat{\tau} f(x) = f(x+\tau)$. 

The equations in the question are their respective eingevectors.